# How to disable or enable sound when QSystemTrayIcon's Message showing?

Tags: c++, qt

How to disable or enable sound when QSystemTrayIcon's Message showing? It must enable or disable only message's sound. Thanks...

Comment: Call [`QSound::play`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsound.html#play) at the same time as you call `showMessage`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make notification on your own, As Qt doesn't provide such functionality (If we're talking about QSystemTrayIcon::showMessage()). It is possible with WINAPI http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773352(VS.85).aspx check dwInfoFlags

I'm not sure, but probably Windows automaticly adds sound for certain notification type, You could experiment with QSystemTrayIcon::MessageIcon enum, but If you need to make more control arround it, you will have to implement your own notification on windows. Also with your own notification you will be able to change notification icon to whatever you want :)